# Instantiating module object on module's file vs. instantiating module object on file that uses it

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, design-patterns, module

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to instantiate a module object on the module's file instead of instantiaing the module object on the file that uses it?

Example of Instantiating module on the module's file:

module.js

```
const someModule = (function() {
  const doSomething = function(id) {
    console.log("doing something");
  };

  return {
    doSomething: doSomething
  };
})();

export someModule;
```

main.js

```
import { someModule } from "./module";
someModule.doSomething();
```

Example of instantiating module on the file that uses it:

module.js

```
const someModule = function() {
  const doSomething = function(id) {
    console.log("doing something");
  };

  return {
    doSomething: doSomething
  };
};

export someModule;
```

main.js

```
import { someModule } from "./module";
someModuleInstance = new someModule();
someMosomeModuleInstance.doSomething();
```

The first example only has "someModule"(from the import statement) on the main file's global scope while the second example has both "someModule" and its instance on the global scope. So is the first example better?

Comment: Both are correct for the appropriate situation. If you need a singleton, then instantiate in the module file. If you need multiple instances, then instantiate where imported. If you're unsure, then you don't need a singleton.

Comment: But will there be any difference in performance?